# JavaScript add an event listener any time and remove the event listener any time

Tags: javascript, dom-events

1. In a web page I have a button when clicked it calls a JavaScript function.
2. In that function I show a modal dialog box and I want to process keystrokes only at this time. That is when the modal dialog is visible.
3. When I close the modal dialog I want to stop the keystroke processing.
4. consider that I click a button and function `sam()` is called.

   ```
   function sam()
    {
     document.onkeypress = function(e) { processKeystroke(e); }
    }
   ```
5. So now a function is attached to the `keypress` event. Whenever a key is pressed the function `processkeystroke` will be called.
   The function `sam` is called only after I display the  modal dialog box.
6. Now I am closing the modal dialog and with that I don't want `function(e) { processKes...}` to be called.
7. What should I do to remove the attached event listener from `document.onkeypress`.
8. Also I would like to have alternatives for the above approach because that one I assumed of my own and I did not refer any specific documentation, so I am really going through trial and error procedure to use event handlers or listeners.
9. So when I call function `sam` I want a function to be attached with the `keypress` event and if I call another function form example `closedialog()` I want that `keypress` listening function to be removed. Because I want to write proper code which should not consume lots of system resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the following code to remove the handler.

```
 document.onkeypress = null;
```

Since you are talking about *attaching* you maybe should check [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) which provides real `bind` (attach) and `unbind` (detach) for events like `keypress`.